# get annotated classes in annotation processors

Tags: annotations

I am trying to use annotation processors.
How can I get classes (Class objects) annotated with the annotation defined by SupportedAnnotationTypes?
I want to access all constructors of the annotated class, which I couldn't do with a TypeMirror.

Thanks in advance. Please let me know if any more information is required.